# longtable cut text overlapping with footnote

Tags: tables, longtable, multirow

I am using longtable since I want to embed at after my text and let it continue on the next page. Also, I am using multirow. Unfortunately, the one of the cell's texts is hanging weirdly into the footnote area.
my code:

```
\documentclass[11pt,titlepage,oneside,openany]{book}
\begin{document}
\begin{longtable}{|l|l|l|l|}
\hline
\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Benchmark\\ Data Set\end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Accuracy \\ / Error\end{tabular} & Model & Paper \\ \hline
\multirow{ 3}{*}{SST-5} & 56.2                                                        & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}BCN+Suffix \\ BiLSTM-Tied+CoVe\end{tabular}                   & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Improved Sentence Modeling \\ using Suffix Bidirectional LSTM\end{tabular}                                                           \\ \cline{2-4} 
                                                                                 & 55.5                                                        & BERTLARGE                                                                                & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Fine-grained Sentiment \\ Classification using BERT\end{tabular}                                                                     \\ \cline{2-4} 
                                                                                 & 54.7                                                        & BCN+ELMo                                                                                 & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Deep contextualized \\ word representations\end{tabular}                                                                             \\ \hline
\multirow{3}{*}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Yelp\\ Review\\ Full\end{tabular}}    & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Error: \\ 27.80\end{tabular}     & XLNet                                                                                    & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}XLNet: Generalized Autoregressive\\ Pretraining for Language Understanding\end{tabular}                                              \\ \cline{2-4} 
                                                                                 & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Error:\\ 28.62\end{tabular}      & BERT\_large+ITPT                                                                         & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}How to Fine-Tune BERT \\ for Text Classification?\end{tabular}                                                                       \\ \cline{2-4} 
                                                                                 & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Error:\\ 29.32\end{tabular}      & BERT\_large                                                                              & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Unsupervised Data Augmentation\\ for Consistency Training\end{tabular}                                                               \\ \hline
\thead\multirow{3}{*}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Amazon \\ Review\\ Full\end{tabular}} & 65.83                                                       & BERT\_large                                                                              & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Unsupervised Data Augmentation\\ for Consistency Training\end{tabular}                                                               \\ \cline{2-4} 
                                                                                 & 65.19                                                       & Deep CNN                                                                                 & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Deep Pyramid Convolutional Neural \\ Networks for Text Categorization\end{tabular}                                                   \\ \cline{2-4} 
                                                                                 & 64.43                                                       & Deep RNN                                                                                 & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Disconnected Recurrent Neural \\ Networks for Text Categorization\end{tabular}                                                       \\ \hline
\multirow{3}{*}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}SemEval \\ 2017 4C\end{tabular}}      & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Error:\\ 0.481\end{tabular}      & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}LSTMs+CNNs\\ ensemble with \\ multiple conv. ops\end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}BB twtr at SemEval-2017 Task 4: \\ Twitter Sentiment Analysis \\ with CNNs and LSTMs\end{tabular}                                    \\ \cline{2-4} 
                                                                                 & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Error:\\ 0.555\end{tabular}      & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Deep Bi-LSTM\\ +attention\end{tabular}                        & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}DataStories at SemEval-2017 Task 4: \\ Deep LSTM with Attention for Message-\\ level and Topic-based Sentiment Analysis\end{tabular} \\ \cline{2-4} 
                                                                                 & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Error:\\ 0.599\end{tabular}      & RNTN                                                                                     & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Amobee at SemEval-2017 Task 4: \\ Deep Learning System for Sentiment \\ Detection on Twitter\end{tabular}                            \\ \hline
\caption[State of the Art Benchmark Results]{State of the Art Benchmark Results}
\label{fig:related_work}
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Thank you in advance

Comment: multirow hides the size of the span and just assumes enough rows will follow to go alongside, that assumption isn't true in longtable, if you must use multirow (it can usually be avoided) then you may need to put a `\pagebreak`  before that row so the spanning cell starts the next page

Comment: Are you aware that your table currently is wider than the available textwidth? You might also want to correct that.

Comment: Thank you two. pagebreak solved it. I adjusted the \\ so that now it fits the textwidth